# Neo4j Match with properties on a variable length path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I checked on the developer manual that you can filter with property on a variable length with relationship like below cypher.

```
MATCH p =(charlie:Person)-[* { blocked:false }]-(martin:Person)
WHERE charlie.name = 'Charlie Sheen' AND martin.name = 'Martin Sheen'
RETURN p
```

What I am looking here is can I filter by some logic on numeric properties on the relationship with a variable length.

For example, change the {blocked:false} in the query to a numeric properties like `{amount_paid}` and filter by `amount_paid > 20`.

So I can hop on Person by the relationship with `amount_paid > 20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the predicate [`ALL`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all):

```
MATCH p=(charlie:Person {name: 'Charlie Sheen')-[*]-(martin:Person {name: 'Martin Sheen')
WHERE ALL(rel in relationships(p) WHERE rel.amount_paind > 20)
RETURN p
```